# System.ArgumentNullException with NetMQ.Msg.Put()

Tags: c#, .net, exception, zeromq, netmq

I'm using NetMQ for inter-process data communication. 
I'm using the NuGet package version 3.3.2.2 on .Net 4.5
I want to create a simple message from a string and send it over a `RequestSocket`.

I keep getting `System.ArgumentNullException` although non of the instances are null in any point.

my self containing code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string exampleString = "hello, world";

    byte[] bytes = new byte[exampleString.Length * sizeof(char)];
    if (bytes == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(exampleString.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    var clientMessage = new NetMQ.Msg();
    clientMessage.InitEmpty();

    if (!clientMessage.IsInitialised)
    {
        return;
    }

    clientMessage.Put(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //throws exception!

}
```

Comment: It's because your `clientMessage` is initialized but doesn't have any MsgType because of `InitEmpty()`.

Comment: @diiN_ How doe you sugget initialize it?

Comment: By using `InitPool` or `InitGC` (look at Guy's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Put` it calls `Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, Data, i, len);`

From [github](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq/blob/master/src/NetMQ/Msg.cs)

```
public void Put([CanBeNull] byte[] src, int i, int len)
{
    if (len == 0 || src == null)
        return;

    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, Data, i, len);
}
```

In this point `Data` is `null`, and [Buffer.BlockCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) throws the `ArgumentNullException`

Try to initalize it by calling `InitPool` or `InitGC`.